# Why am i getting a javascript function not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is My code, which was working fine previously suddenly a javascript reference error has crept in..

this is **where i call my javascript function..**

```
<li class="pull-right"><a href="#"><button class="btn nopadding-verticle" onclick="showSendInviteSection()"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Send Invite</button></a></li>
```

Here is javaSctipt function itself

```
 function showSendInviteSection(){

    $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.message").show();
    $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input[name="email"]").show();
    $("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body span.loader-gif").hide();
    $('.generated_link_section').slideDown("fast");

 }
```

Function is within script tag.

here is generated Link modal..

```
<!-- GENERATE LINK SECTION -->
<div id='generateLinkModal' class="modal hide generated_link_section" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="generateLinkModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$('.generated_link_section').slideUp()" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
             <h3 id="generateLinkModalLabel" align="left">Send Invites</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body row-fluid" align="left">
       <span class="loader-gif" style="display:none;"><img src="<?php echo $baseURL?>/wizshark/img/ajax-loader-horizontal.gif"></span>
       Email: <input type ="text" name="email" multiple="" autofocus="" pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$" style="display:none;width:91%;"/>
      Links:<input type="text" name ="link"readonly="readonly" style="display:none;width:91%;cursor:text;"/>
     <span class="message" style="display:none;"></span>

</div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" onclick="getGeneratedLink();" aria-hidden="true" >Send</button>
             <!--<button class="btn btn-success refresh_button">Refresh</button>-->
</div>
```

what is going wrong with this code?? browser debugger says, reference error, ***function is not defined.***

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: There is syntax error in line `$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input[name="email"]").show();` it should be `$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input[name='email']").show();`. Use quotes properly

Comment: How else, then i retrieve the value of input name = email ??

Comment: @Himanshu97 Delimit your strings using single quotes rather than double quotes, or escape the double quotes that are part of the string rather than delimiting it.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). You cannot nest buttons and anchors.

Comment: @Quentin using single quotes solved the problem..

Comment: @Himanshu97 — Using single quotes would not make your HTML valid.

Comment: @Satpal — Could you make that an answer so it can be accepted? (Make it community wiki if you don't think you should get points for typo spotting). Since it is a typo, the question should probably be closed for that reason. It isn't of value in the long term.

Comment: @Quentin, Posted it as community wiki. Its a typo so thought comment is good enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes properly.

There is syntax error in line

```
$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input[name="email"]").show();
```

it should be

```
$("#generateLinkModal div.modal-body input[name='email']").show();
```